# Read message dropped in log file of cassandra

Tags: performance, cassandra

I have following messages in cassandra log file.

INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-06-14 12:10:25,515 MessagingService.java (line 663) 637 READ messages dropped in last 5000ms
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-06-14 12:10:35,528 MessagingService.java (line 663) 486 READ messages dropped in last 5000ms
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-06-14 12:10:45,542 MessagingService.java (line 663) 431 READ messages dropped in last 5000ms

At the same time when I am accessing data from thrift library then requests are getting timed out.
It means that the messages are timed out for data transfer within cassandra servers.
Can we fix this problem by increasing rcp_time_out
rpc_timeout_in_ms: 10000

Thanks
Manish

Comment: Running into the same issue when running a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WHERE index_id = foo, then cqlsh stops working and I can't connect using cqlsh until supposedly the query has ended, which might be a couple of minutes? Did you solve this?